# VB script to convert one excel file format to another

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have the following VB script to save an Excel file (tab delimted format) to an Excel file (Excel workbook or Excel 97-2003 workbook format)

```
 Dim objExcel, objWorkbook 
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\SCC-fs\reports\aaa.xls")
 objExcel.Visible = True

 objWorkbook.SaveAs "new.xls",56


 WScript.Quit
```

ERROR: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients
What is wrong ?

Comment: What is the error line?

Comment: If I remove the SaveAs line, then error window does not appear. So I think it is this line which is causing the error

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try to specify full path for target file, and check if you have an access to the target folder. Anyway you can copy the file into target folder via FSO, then open it locally and save it as.